# Can I create guides by asking and answering own questions?

Tags: discussion

I am traveling now and often trying to find something like "How to get from X to Y by public transport?". The information which is found by Google is often outdated, especially on TripAdvisor, where you can find answers from 2008. On that site you can not update info as the topic is closed.

So should I ask question and immediately provide the current answer. And in future other people can update the info if something changes?

Comment: You've missed a perfect opportunity by not replying to your own question right now :)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you certainly can. Which is why StackExchange allows you immediately post the answer as well.